# Can't extract an email address from a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape an email address from a webpage. When there is any email address available in any similar page, the email sign is there. However, I can't fetch it using the script below. What I get instead is this link `https://www.yell.com/customerneeds/sendenquiry/sendtoone/100040736756000120`.

[webpage address](https://www.yell.com/biz/east-london-only-london-901717573/)

I've tried with:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

base = "https://www.yell.com"
link = "https://www.yell.com/biz/east-london-only-london-901717573/"

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(link,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
email = urljoin(base,soup.select_one("a[data-tracking='ENQUIRY:SEND']")["href"])
print(email)
```

> How can I fetch the email address from that page?

Comment: I don't see an email there. What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: There is no email on the link given.

Comment: I think you got it wrong buddy. The email sign is there to use the service provided by the website to send an email through them, that means they are not giving you an email address, but they are providing a service which you can utilize to send a message which will be sent to the client through the website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There are no email addresses on that page.** This is a typical way that is used to make contacting possible *without giving an email address to the public*.

What happens when you press the "Send enquiry" -button is that your browser sends a HTTP POST request towards some address*, to a webserver, which then handles your enquiry. The webserver *might* send an email to some address, but it *might not* aswell. For example, the webserver might just add an entry to a database, and then some user might see your enquiry though a web interface.

---

** This you could check yourself using the browser developer tools and checking the Network tab while pressing the "Send enquiry" -button. I did not want to send trash to them just to check where the data is sent.*